# Formatting error in visual studio code, don't know how to fix?

Tags: c, visual-studio

When I try to format my code, it gives me this error. Anyone know a fix?

```
Formatting failed:
"c:\Users\straw\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.3.1/bin/../LLVM/bin/clang-format.exe" -style="{ BasedOnStyle: Google, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4,  AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -4, NamespaceIndentation: All, FixNamespaceComments: false }spaceIndentation: All, FixNamespaceComments: false }" -fallback-style="LLVM" -assume-filename="c:\Users\straw\Desktop\Opdrachten Toegepaste Inf\Programmeren Embedded\Week 1\Flashing LED\src\main.c"
YAML:1:237: error: Unexpected token in Key Value.
  { BasedOnStyle: Google, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4,  AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -4, NamespaceIndentation: All, FixNamespaceComments: false }spaceIndentation: All, FixNamespaceComments: false }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^
  YAML:1:3: error: Map key must be a scalar
  { BasedOnStyle: Google, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4,  AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -4, NamespaceIndentation: All, FixNamespaceComments: false }spaceIndentation: All, FixNamespaceComments: false }
    ^
  Error parsing -style: invalid argument
```

Comment: It looks like `,` is missing after `}`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you, i got it!